# Error occurs on calling the WebMethod "Client found response content type of 'text/html; charset=us-ascii', but expected 'text/xml'

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, windows-mobile

I am calling a web method which takes a dataset as parameter from my Windows Mobile application.

I am getting this error:

> Client found response content type of 'text/html; charset=us-ascii',
>   but expected 'text/xml'.

I do not understand what's the exact error.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the content type that the web service is returning text/html content while your mobile application is expecting xml to work on so I think you will need to make sure that your web service is returning xml.